# How do I reset all BITS jobs from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

In Windows 7, the BITSAdmin command has been deprecated in favor of BITS PowerShell cmdlets. What is the PowerShell equivalent of the command `bitsadmin /reset /allusers`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the available cmdlets and the documentation of them as well as `bitsadmin` I'd say

```
Get-BitsTransfer -AllUsers | Remove-BitsTransfer
```

will do what you want.

Comment: For powershell newbies run this line first: import-module bitstransfer